# Allocating, filling and manipulating pointer array with pointer to structure

Tags: c, pointers, calloc

Allocating, filling and manipulating pointer array with pointer to structure

I have a list of tests without knowing the number of tests at start.
The number of test and the content of each test will come from a database later on.
The sequence of the tests should be easily changeable and a test should be individually deleteable / insertable into the sequence.

Since I can determine the number of test querying the database I thought of first allocating an array of pointers to all the test, then allocating the memory for each test separately.
By that I could reorder the sequence by just swapping pointers to the test and would also be able to remove or insert new test into the sequence.

I wrote a little program to be able to quick check with gdt.

Sadly the compiler does not accept the assignment of the test (allocated mem) to the pointer array (also allocated mem).

```
#define MAX_TEST_NAME                100

typedef struct sTestT
{
  char                      cTested;                             // Output of this Test
  char                      cEnabled;                            //
  char                      cName[MAX_TEST_NAME+1];
} sTest;


void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf ("Double Pointer Test for GDB\n");

  int i,j;
  i = 7;                                             // A random number for this program, to be able to change it with gdb

  sTest*  psTestPtr;
  sTest*  psTestPtrArray;
  sTest*  psTestPtrArrayOriginal;

  // We first allocate an array of pointers to the Tests, NOT an array of the Tests
  psTestPtrArray = calloc (i, sizeof(sTest*));       // allocate the pointer array
  psTestPtrArrayOriginal = psTestPtrArray;           // store original pointer to free memory later


  // Now we allocate each test seperatly and let the psTestPtrArray point to the test
  for (j=0; j<i; j++)
  {
    // Now we allocate ONE trigger each time to be able to free them seperately
    psTestPtr = calloc (1, sizeof(sTest));
    psTestPtr->cTested = j;
    *psTestPtrArray = &psTestPtr;                    // <-------------- Does NOT compile
    psTestPtrArray++;                                // Next pointer to another Test
  }

  // Working with test omitted

  // Free Tests and pointer array
  psTestPtrArray = psTestPtrArrayOriginal;           // Restore initial pointer to be able to walk through array
  for (j=0; j<i; j++)
  {
    free (*psTestPtrArray);                          // <-------------- Does NOT compile
    psTestPtrArray++;
  }

  free (psTestPtrArray); 
} // main
```

Any suggestion ?

Thanks.
Rainer

Comment: You're not using a pointer array, though you seem to be *almost* allocating one. Pointer-arrays contain... *pointers*.

Comment: psTestPtrArray should have type sTest**, and assignment should be psTestPtrArray[j] = psTestPtr. Something like that, your code is pretty hard to read due to the overly verbose naming.

Comment: Note: With `psTestPtrArray = calloc (i, sizeof(sTest*));`,  on review, one needs to check that `psTestPtrArray` points to a `sTest`.   With `psTestPtrArray = calloc (i, sizeof *psTestPtrArray);`,  on review, that check not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring variables of wrong types.When you assign them you should have got self explanatory errors.

```
sTest*  psTestPtr;        //pointer to a sTest
sTest**  psTestPtrArray;  //Pointer to an array of pointers to sTest
sTest**  psTestPtrArrayOriginal; //same as above
```

And

```
*psTestPtrArray = &psTestPtr;
```

should be

```
*psTestPtrArray = psTestPtr;
```

because `psTestPtr` is already a pointer to `sTest`.No need to take its address.
Also it would be easier if you use array indices to allocate memory for each `sTest` rather than incrementing the pointer variables.

Comment: Also worth noting. The final `free` will invoke *undefined behavior* unless either `psTestPtrArray` is once-again restored to `psTestPtrArrayOriginal` immediately before, or just use `psTestPtrArrayOriginal` as the actual argument to the final `free`.